# Does saving my progress on a U1-synced file/folder put unneccesary strain on the servers?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I love Ubuntu One and I use it all the time. I have my documents and music composition folders set to sync. It's been a real boon. However, sometimes I feel that constantly saving my progress forces the file to sync dozens and dozens of times to the servers. It seems wasteful to me so I've been disconnecting U1 until I'm finished working on a project.

Is this an unnecessary action that I am taking? I know it's using Amazon's storage but I'm still paranoid that I'm costing Canonical money when I constantly save my progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's totally fine to save progress as you go, we're doing a lot of work to make this cheaper for both the user and our servers.
I'd encourage you to use it however you feel most comfortable  :)

Answer (score 3):

i would not worry about this. Given the observed speed of syncing, I would not consider Canonical's Amazon storage system to be even nearly overwhelmed.

If you are concerned about ensuring the service remains viable, you may wish to consider [upgrading your storage plan](https://one.ubuntu.com/plans/) to get more benefit and help support the infrastructure.